# Keep nested object in a JSON payload without modeling it with GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

In my service I am:

- Getting a JSON object from a remote server
- Partially parse this object to do my logic
- Return the full object to a remote caller

**The object is quite complex and I only need very few fields from it.**

I would like to create an **incomplete** domain class that exposes the fields I'm interested for my logic but that keeps track of all object tree once it is serialized again as answer to the caller.

Is there any generic object in GSON library that fulfill my needs?

Example of JSON:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "payload": { /* complex object here */ }
}
```

I only need the id and would like to model only this field. Example:

```
public class MyDomain {
    int id;
    JSonGenericObject payload;
}
```

Still I need the payload reference because at the end the full object must be transmitted to the remote caller which started the procedure

Comment: Does this JSON data appear nested inside the complete JSON document? If not, would it be possible to read the complete JSON as string, deserialize it as your `MyDomain` but then return that complete JSON string? Or do you need to also transform the JSON data in some way?

Comment: @Marcono1234 That's a good possibility, thanks. It is feasible, but requires to move around the answer (from read part, to logic part, to write-back part) as a String, which is not that elegant. But I'll keep it in mind